# Problem with Azure AD B2C MSAL authentication

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I'm trying to add basic authentication to a Vue.js spa. I'm following the tutorial on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app

In case of the sample SPA provied by MS everything works. When I try to do the same in Vue.js I get the following error:
*"ClientAuthError: access_token_entity_null: Access token entity is null, please check logs and cache to ensure a valid access token is present."* when doing

```
        .then(handleResponse)
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

However after refreshing the page user seems to be logged in:
`myMSALObj.getAllAccounts()`
returnes the account used during the login.

What I may be doing wrong? I was unable to find any useful info about it :(

Comment: This is a known issue that will be fixed in the next version. Try an older version as a mitigation for now.

Comment: Using older version solved the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments using an older version of the library solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to have been solved in version [2.14.2](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/changelog.md)

Instead of downgrading you should try upgrading :-)